Android 14 - Bluetooth is slow
I am struggling with adapting my app to Android 14. Finally app starts working but not entirely.
Bluetooth transmission works but became slow. It is not possible to observe values change in real time. They are excessively postponed.
I am using Bluetooth Classic (2).
Under older version (Android 10) everything is going smoothly.
Does anyone have any experience on this topic ?
I have tried to modify manifest file adding:
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />

but it didn't change a speed.

What device are you using? Or are you testing this on multiple files? What other contents does your manifest file have? i.e. does it have BLUETOOTH, BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, and BLUETOOTH_CONNECTION permissions?

Thank you for your reply.

I'm testing it on Motorola Moto G4 and Samsung Galaxy A14.


Did you try adding BLUETOOTH, BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, and BLUETOOTH_CONNECTION to your manifest file and also request these permissions at runtime? If so, can you please share the manifest file and the code that shows this being requested at runtime?

Sorry for late reply. I have add all what Bluetooth options you have mentioned in manifest. App is working, no errors. The only disadvantage is a slow transmission. I don't know how to attach a file.
